# How to perform operation between JSON joined data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have two JSON strings:

```
json1 = [{"hc-key":"ar-tf","value":221},{"hc-key":"ar-ba","value":10820},{"hc-key":"ar-sj","value":230}]

json2 = [{"hc-key":"ar-ba","value":2890151},{"hc-key":"ar-sj","value":15625084},{"hc-key":"ar-tf","value":367828}]
```

what I'd like to do is to join them by **"hc-key"**, into a new JSON string, where the new **"value"** is the result of dividing the value in json1 by the value in json2. In JavaScript.

Note that the data in json2 is not in the same order as in json1, BUT they both have the exact same keys.

The resulting JSON should be:

```
 result = [{"hc-key":"ar-ba","value":10820/2890151},{"hc-key":"ar-sj","value":230/15625084},{"hc-key":"ar-tf","value":221/367828}]
```

*(I've ommited the resulting values for clarification)*

thanks.

Comment: you don't manipulate json strings. decode the strings to a native array/object, merge those, then re-encode to json. json's basically a transport/wrapper format, and not intended to be manipulated.

Comment: From my experience, joins are much better done server side before sending to the client. Yet, sometime you're force to do it client side and it's not a trivial programming task. That said, you might want to check out some of the javascript database like [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/). These aren't really a solution to your question, but they might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As a matter of fact both JSON strings are in the DB so they can be manipulated server side using Newtonsoft.JSON. Wich I think is the right thing to do. I'll take suggestions in C# as well.

Comment: Any anwers in C#? I think it would be best if done server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert is correct that joins are better server side but what you want to do is certainly possible just using some JavaScript loops.

I did not bother with error handling for this example, but I would also recommend confirming you have real numbers before dividing and that you are not dividing by zero.

```js
var json1 = [
  {"hc-key":"ar-tf","value":221},
  {"hc-key":"ar-ba","value":10820},
  {"hc-key":"ar-sj","value":230}];

var json2 = [
  {"hc-key":"ar-ba","value":2890151},
  {"hc-key":"ar-sj","value":15625084},
  {"hc-key":"ar-tf","value":367828}];

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++)
{
    var key = json1[i]['hc-key'];
    for(var j = 0; j < json2.length; j++) {
        if(json2[j]['hc-key'] == key) {
            result.push({
                "hc-key":key,
                "value": json1[i]['value'] / json2[j]['value']
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
    
//show results
var key, value;
var $results = $('.results tbody');

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    key = result[i]['hc-key'];
    value = result[i]['value'];
    $results.append('<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
td {
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>results:<b>

<table class="results">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @tellez, I tried your code with the code snippet but it doens't show any results. Also I tried it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: open the javascript console then run the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a functional way to do it. This way will also work with the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) observables for async programming.

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};


result = json1.map(function(obj1) {
    return json2.
        filter(function(obj2) {return obj2["hc-key"] == obj1["hc-key"]}).
        map(function(obj2) {
        return {
            "hc-key": obj1["hc-key"],
            "value": obj1.value / obj2.value
        };
    });
}).concatAll()
```

Comment: Interesting answer since it addresses the larger problem of combining data coming across the wire asynchronously. That's a separate issue, but it's what makes client side joins grow in complexity.